# Borders containing BlurEffect do not work with CornerRadius

Tags: c#, wpf

I encountered a problem where the ThemePanel's CornerRadius was overridden by its own BlurEffect on top, and instead of CornerRadius 10, its BlurEffect caused the ThemePanel to become cornerRadius 0.

This is how I wrote it:

```xml
    <Border Name="ThemePanel" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="10" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Border.Background>

        <Border.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="10" RenderingBias="Quality" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
```

Here is a photo of its condition:
[image]

In the image with the Windows 11 interface, I use C++ to get the path of the Desktop WallPaper is on, and then use `((ImageBrush)MainWindow.Instance.ThemePanel.Background).ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sourcePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));`

I'm sure I've adjusted Window to `AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" WindowStyle="None"`

Simply, I want to make its edges rounded successfully while being blurred by BlurEffect.

Thanks for reading!

Edit:
solution applied:

```
<Image Name="ThemeImage" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Rect="0,0,960,540"/>
                </Image.Clip>
                
                <Image.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="10" RenderingBias="Performance" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                </Image.Effect>
            </Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the border Thickness.
Full example:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2023.CornerRadiusWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CornerRadiusWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" WindowStyle="None">
    <Border Name="ThemePanel" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="5"
            CornerRadius="10" ClipToBounds="True"
            Background="Aqua">
        <Border.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="10"/>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for giving me the solution, I tried it and in the meantime I thought of a better way so that the borders of the Blur Effect don't bleed out.